# useLazyQuery and useQuery onCompleted not running when variable doesn't change or is changed to null

Tags: graphql, react-apollo

**What i want to do:** I have a few category toggle buttons. I want to show only the data of the categories that has been checked.

**My approach:** The function for showing the filtered data checks the array of buttons, see which one is ticked, then reads the cache of the query.

```
const getFilteredData = () => {
    try {
      const freshFilteredData = []
      for (var i = 0; i < chipData.length; i ++){
          if (chipData[i].clicked){
            const itineraryData = client.readQuery({
              query: GET_ITINERARY,
              variables: {itineraryId : chipData[i].label}
            })
            const wantedData = itineraryData.getItinerary.dayPlans;
            freshFilteredData.push(wantedData)
          }
      }
      setFilteredData(freshFilteredData)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
```

However, cache can only be read when a query has been fired. So I use an if-else statement to decide when to call the `getFilteredData` function. If the button is just checked, then I call the query (when it's completed it will call the `getFilteredData` function), if the button is unchecked, I call the `getFilteredData` directly.

```
  const toggleClick = clickedChip => () => {
    const chipClone = [...chipData];
    const objectIndex = chipData.findIndex(
      chip => chip.key === clickedChip.key
    );
    chipClone[objectIndex].clicked = !chipData[objectIndex].clicked;
    setChipData(chipClone);

    if (chipClone[objectIndex].clicked) {
      getItinerary({variables: {itineraryId: clickedChip.label}});
    } else {
      console.log('fire2')
      getFilteredData();
    }
  };
```

And here's my lazy query:

```
const [getItinerary] = useLazyQuery(GET_ITINERARY, {
    onCompleted(data){
      console.log('fired');
      getFilteredData()
    }
  });
```

**My problem:** if I clicked on the same button thrice.

1. click (runs query)
2. unclicked (doesn't run query)
3. clicked (doesn't run query, so doesn't run `getFilteredData` function, because query doesn't run
   `onCompleted`. And since it is clicked, it doesn't execute the 'else' statement either, so `getFilteredData` is not run at all)

That screws up the filtering.

**I could** get rid of the if-else statement and execute the `getFilteredData` function at two places:

```
const toggleClick = clickedChip => () => {
    const chipClone = [...chipData];
    const objectIndex = chipData.findIndex(
      chip => chip.key === clickedChip.key
    );
    chipClone[objectIndex].clicked = !chipData[objectIndex].clicked;
    setChipData(chipClone);

    getItinerary({variables: {itineraryId: clickedChip.label}});
    getFilteredData();
  };
```

This will cover all bases, but I was wondering if there's a more elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

the thing you have missed is apollo by defaults stores the result of all issued query in its local cache, any subsequent call to a query fetches the result from cache(unless you have changed the fetch policy).

instead of we manually checking whether its a first time call, delegate that responsibility to apollo.

My recommendation for the flow would be

1) maintain a state variable for the clicked chip label

2) change the above label in the onClick callback of the chip, that will fire the query

3) let apollo decide whether its a first time call or subsequent call

```
 const [chipLabel, setChipLabel] = useState(<Initial label here>) // pass the initial value 
//that query expects

    // pass the state variable above in the query
    const itineraryData = useQuery({
                  query: GET_ITINERARY,
                  variables: {itineraryId : chipLabel}
                })

    // all the toggle button should have a click handler like below
    onClick={() =>{//call the setChipLabel}}
```

Open the network tabs, click any filter button multiple times, only during the first click a n/w call will be issued. Apollo client is smart to read from the cache, if the data is already available, by default the fetch policy is "cache-first".

Comment: my issue is that if i clicked the same chip 3 times - 1st click(selected; run query and gets to onCompleted), 2nd click(unselected; doesn't get run), 3rd click(selected; fetches from query so doesn't get to onCompleted) BUT i have logic i want to run at onCompleted.